# Can the word "output" be used as a verb

Tags: word-usage

I'd like to inquire about the exact usage of the word "output" in the following two examples:

> This data were analyzed using a traditional pipeline. This streamline output a number for each metric of interest.
>
> This data were analyzed using a traditional pipeline. The output of this streamline is one number for each metric of interest.

In the first example "output"  was used as a verb and in the second sentence it was used as a noun. Is this usage correct? In the dictionary the word "output" was reported as a verb and as a noun. But the usage as a verb is not common. Am I still able to use it as a verb like in the examples above? In other words, is this usage common between native speakers?

Comment: Since *streamline* is singular, I would expect the corresponding verb to be *outputs*, unless the concept of the *streamline* in this context actually represents multiple items.

Comment: You appear to have answered your own question: Output can be used as both a noun and verb, but the verbal use is not common.  // Also "This data was" or "These data were"  at the start.

Comment: @choster: The verb form in the first example is incredibly awkward to parse, but given the data ***were*** analysed, we should assume that ***output*** is a syntactically valid (but stylistically hopeless) Past Tense form.

Comment: @James K: I see no reason to think the verb usage of ***output*** is not common. It's just a really, *really, **really*** bad choice in OP's exact context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Thank you for your feedback. Would you please suggest a suitable synonym to "output" that can be used as an acceptable alternative.

Comment: The whole thing is moderately terrible - *These* data, if nothing else - but yes, "output" is being used as a verb. If you mentally substitute "produced" it'll make more sense.

Comment: @goro: I'm not familiar with your use of *streamline* as a noun - but putting that aside, it would be more natural (and easier for readers to parse) if you said, for example, *This streamline **generates** a number for each metric of interest.* And personally, I'd much prefer ***value*** rather than ***number*** there, but this is just a stylistic choice that doesn't make much difference in terms of how easy it is to read and understand. Also, I don't like treating ***data*** as a plural noun (again, just a personal thing - many people are quite happy with that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is okay to use **output** as a verb. Just google for "to output the" (using the quotation marks) and you will come across multiple instances of it being used as a verb.

Example from Google Books:

> This means that P0 is used to transmit the low eight bits of the address and **to output the** eight bits of data.

Comment: It is pretty much possible to use any English lexical word as a verb in the proper context. Also as a noun and an adjective, in other proper contexts. A good dictionary will point out and distinguish noun, verb, and adjective uses of a word.